# during creation of pandas DataFrame ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get pandas to read specific column values from an excel file, and allow me to manipulate specific individual elements within the specific column values by reading all the values into a numpy array.

Below is the code I am using

```
   cols= 'A, AO, BB, BC'
   df= pd.read_excel(path_to_excel, sheet_name=None, usecols=cols)
   f1= pd.DataFrame(df, index=[0])

   df1.to_numpy()
```

My df has `124412 rows X 4 columns`

But for `df1` I get the following error `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`.

I realise it is kind of a stupid question, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `sheet_name=None` from your code.

```
cols= 'A, AO, BB, BC'
df= pd.read_excel(path_to_excel, usecols=cols)
f1= pd.DataFrame(df, index=[0])

df1.to_numpy()
```

The default value for argument `sheet_name` is `Sheet1`, not `None`.
If you use `sheet_name=None` pandas reads all worksheets, and returns a dictionary with **sheet names** as *keys*, and dataframes as values. For example:

```py
cols= 'A, B, C'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=cols)
df
```

**Returns:**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | foo1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | foo2 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | foo3 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | foo4 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 | foo5 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | foo1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | foo2 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 | foo3 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 | foo4 |
| 9 | 4 | 0 | foo5 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | foo1 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 | foo2 |
| 12 | 2 | 0 | foo3 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 | foo4 |
| 14 | 4 | 0 | foo5 |

**While:**

```py
cols = 'A, B, C'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, usecols=cols)
```

**Returns:**

```py
{'Sheet1':     A  B     C
 0   0  0  foo1
 1   1  1  foo2
 2   2  0  foo3
 3   3  1  foo4
 4   4  0  foo5
 5   0  0  foo1
 6   1  1  foo2
 7   2  0  foo3
 8   3  1  foo4
 9   4  0  foo5
 10  0  0  foo1
 11  1  1  foo2
 12  2  0  foo3
 13  3  1  foo4
 14  4  0  foo5}
```

Comment: @ingwesen_erik I now assume that with `sheet_name` removed, the `df1` I obtain is a dataframe upon which I can easily do the operations like `df1.iloc()`

Comment: @TK Yes, that's it